# dynamic text highlighting using ajax in backbone js model

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I am working on a text search feature in my project in backbone js. Whenever there is a keyup, searchFunction will be called and only data containing the particular search keyword will be displayed. I want to highlight the text keyword (search_keyword) which is in data and been set using self.set(data). Any thoughts?

```
initialize: function() {
this.listenTo(this, 'keyup: search', searchFunction);

searchFunction: function(model) {
var self = this;
$.ajax({
 url: '/c/page1/method_name',
data: {
   '_format': 'json',
          'p_id': self.get('id'),
          'page_number': self.get('currentPage'),
          'search_keyword': self.get('search')
}
}).done(function(data) {
        self.set(data);
        }
      });
    },
```